# Angular dependent $http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm trying to fetch data via post request and the API I'm querying from returns a maximal 50 elements. This worked great so far, but now we have some uses cases where it's mandatory to receive an higher indeterminate number of elements.
The `$http`-method returns a promise but I must rely on this data to make another request.
My simplified code:

```
var data =
    "q=" + term
    "&timestamp=" + latest

$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            let dataList = response.data.list; 
            if(dataList.length > 50)
               /*TODO: new query with other timestamp-value*/
            return dataList ;

        },
        function(response) {
            if(shouldLog){
                console.log("[DebuggingService] " + response);
            }
        }
    );
```

Is there a way to combine multiple http requests depending on the request before?

**EDIT**

There is not pagination. So it's mandatory to change the timestamp value. (taking the latest timestamp of the response)

Comment: Is there any pagination information in the response data? And how does paging get defined in request?

Comment: coog callout. I added additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap that request in a function that can also be called recursively inside `then()` to return another request promise

Something like:

```
function getData(term, time, res = []) {

  var data = "q=" + term + "&timestamp=" + time
  // return the $http promise
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data
  }).then(function(response) {
    let dataList = response.data.list;
    // merge new data into final results array
    res = res.concat(dataList);

    if (dataList.length > 50) {
       const timeStampFromResponse = //????
      // return new request promise
      return getData(term, timeStampFromResponse, res)
    }
    // return final array
    return res;

  })
}

getData(term, latest).then(function(results) {
  // all results available here
}).catch(function(response) {
  if (shouldLog) {
    console.log("[DebuggingService] " + response);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this:

```
var data =
  "q=" + term + "&timestamp=" + latest;

var amounts = 2;
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:ruby+topic:rails';

call(url, data, checkForMore);

function call(url, data, callback) {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data
  }).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log('------------');
    callback(data);
  });
}

function checkForMore(data){
    if (amounts > 0){
        amounts -= 1;
      var newData = "q=" + term +
                                    "&timestamp=" + data.SomehowGetLastestTimestamp;
      call(url, newData, checkForMore);
    } else {
        // Save it maybe?
    }
}
```

This is a very rough example, and probably doesn't work but it gets you a good idea what to do.

Basically, have a callback method that is called on the `.then` anonymous function. Then you can pass in the data and check to see if you need to call it more. (Based on your situations). If you do, then just call the `call` function again, but update your data.